# Can I make pprint in python3 not split strings, like in python2?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x, pprint

Is there a way to tell `pprint` in Python 3 not to split strings on whitespace? Python 2's `pprint` did not do this. Can this behavior be disabled? I looked through the source for `pprint` and it doesn't look like there's an option I saw for this.

Can I trick it somehow?

Here's an example of what I'm getting:

```
>>> PP.pprint("ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ ZZZZZ",width=-1,compact=True)
('ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ '
 'ZZZZZ')
```

And here's what I want:

```
>>> PP.pprint("ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ ZZZZZ",width=-1,compact=True)
('ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ ZZZZZ')
```

To clarify, I do want it to obey widths, just not for strings. So when I see eg:

```
PP.pprint(["ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ","CATS"])
```

I want:

```
['ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ',
 'CATS']
```

Not:

```
['ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ '
 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ',
 'CATS']
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could just set the `width` option to a really large value, such as `sys.maxsize`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import pprint as PP
>>> PP.pprint("ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ ZZZZZ",width=sys.maxsize,compact=True)
'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ ZZZZZ'
```

Setting `width` to `-1` has no special meaning.

The only other option is to subclass the `PrettyPrinter()` class, and wrapping the `_format()` method:

```
import sys
from pprint import PrettyPrinter

class NoStringWrappingPrettyPrinter(PrettyPrinter):
    def _format(self, object, *args):
        if isinstance(object, str):
            width = self._width
            self._width = sys.maxsize
            try:
                super()._format(object, *args)
            finally:
                self._width = width
        else:
            super()._format(object, *args)

NoStringWrappingPrettyPrinter().pprint(yourobject)
```

This sets the width to `sys.maxsize` only for strings:

```
>>> NoStringWrappingPrettyPrinter().pprint(["ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ ZZZZZ", "CATS"])
['ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ ZZZZZ',
 'CATS']
```

Comment: I guess it didn't grow an option for this in the meantime?

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard: nope.

Comment: We already subclassed PrettyPrinter so the latter solution worked fine. I agree with the OP that Python 2 behavior is better when formatting lists and dicts, but I can see use cases where Python 3 approach works better. It's also strange that only Unicode strings, not bytes, are split like this. It would be best if there was an option to control this behavior.

Comment: @PekkaKlärck: the `pprint` module is in dire need of a rewrite. I fear it currently is too gnarly to support new features like this easily.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've noticed that. We wanted to slightly modify formatting strings and bytes and that wasn't as easy as it could have been. That said, adding support for not splitting strings shouldn't be that complicated.

Comment: Just noticed in my testing that Python 3.4 doesn't split long byte strings but Python 3.5+ do. Needed to change `isinstance(object, str)`in  the above solution to `isinstance(object, (str, bytes, bytearray))` to fix that.

Answer (score 3):

For list, you can try json.dump. Code:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint
import sys

li = ['zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzz', 'cats']

print("pprint directly:")
pprint(li)
print('-' * 20)
print("pprint with large width:")
pprint(li, width=sys.maxsize, compact=True)
print('-' * 20)
print("json dumps:")
print(json.dumps(li, indent=4))
```

output:

```
pprint directly:
['zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz '
 'zzz',
 'cats']
--------------------
pprint with large width:
['zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzz', 'cats']
--------------------
json dumps:
[
    "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzz",
    "cats"
]
```

Setting a large width makes pprint not wraping even the list object is very long

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you need to set the width to be the length of your string + 3 (for the quotes on either side and the newline) at an absolute minimum.

```
>>> x = 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ ZZZZZ'
>>> PP.pprint(x, width=len(x))
'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ '
'ZZZZZ'
>>> PP.pprint(x, width=len(x) + 3)
'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ ZZZZZ'
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach, similar to that of Martijn Pieters, but which relies less on the internals of `pprint` is to subclass `PrettyPrinter` and override [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.PrettyPrinter.format).
Inside you can delegate to `super().format` but in the result you can fake the length of strings, such that they won't be split. This relies on the output stream (e.g. `sys.stdout` or `StringIO()`) not looking at the string length.

```py
class Python2PrettyPrinter(pprint.PrettyPrinter):
    class _fake_short_str(str):
        def __len__(self):
            return 1 if super().__len__() else 0

    def format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level):
        res = super().format(object, context, maxlevels, level)
        if isinstance(object, str):
            return (self._fake_short_str(res[0]), ) + res[1:]
        return res

    from io import StringIO
    assert StringIO().write(_fake_short_str('_' * 1000)) == 1000


Python2PrettyPrinter().pprint(["TEST " * 20] * 2)
# ['TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST ',
#  'TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST ']
```

The 100% clean way would be to modify the behavior of `format` for all supported container classes, and substitute every string for a custom object which has the same representation.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work for a list of strings until I set `__len__()` to always return `0`. I'm not sure if that would work in general though.